# How to change background-colour with href?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a page, https://adsler.co.uk/jobs/, but when I try to change the background colour of the adverts using `a href=`, it doesn't work.

Tried:

```
a [href="https://adsler.co.uk/job/nicos-cleaning-service-london-6-cleaner/" ] {background-color: 
white;}

a:active [href="https://adsler.co.uk/job/nicos-cleaning-service-london-6-cleaner/"] {background- 
color: white;}
```

Nothing.

I'm using WordPress and the page is controlled by a plugin, so difficulty to edit php/html, or even to find div class controlling entries,

Comment: Remove the space between `a` and the selector. `a[....]`. Also, you've posted a few questions recently and should really include the HTML to the adverts (or at least one of them) in the question, rather than a link to your site.

Comment: Hi @disinfor, how are you :-)?

Comment: Yeah, i can't find my the div class to be able to post relevant html...that why linked to page case anyone has any ideas...

Comment: @disinfor, hmm good thinking but doesn't work...

Comment: It does work. I've created a minimal example/answer using the mark up from your site.

Comment: Ok. Dunno man. I put it in my css...

Comment: Put comments on my answer so I can help you. You probably needed to be more specific in your CSS selectors. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the space between the `a` and the `[href...]`.

```css
ul.job_listings li.job_listing a[href="https://adsler.co.uk/job/nicos-cleaning-service-london-6-cleaner/"] {
  background-color: white;
}

ul.job_listings li.job_listing a:active[href="https://adsler.co.uk/job/nicos-cleaning-service-london-6-cleaner/"] {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="job_listings">
  <li class="post-7252 job_listing type-job_listing status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry job-type-freelance" data-longitude="" data-latitude="" style="visibility: visible;">
    <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/job/nicos-cleaning-service-london-6-cleaner/">
      <h3>Cleaner</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="post-6399 job_listing type-job_listing status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry job-type-temporary" data-longitude="" data-latitude="" style="visibility: visible;">
    <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/job/nicos-cleaning-service-london-5-cleaners-needed/">
      <h3>Cleaners Needed</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="post-6379 job_listing type-job_listing status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry job-type-temporary" data-longitude="" data-latitude="" style="visibility: visible;">
    <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/job/customer-assistant/">
      <h3>Customer Assistant – Chelsea</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="post-6169 job_listing type-job_listing status-expired has-post-thumbnail hentry job-type-freelance" data-longitude="" data-latitude="" style="visibility: visible;">
    <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/job/cleaner/">
      <h3>Cleaner</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's a fiddle to view:
https://jsfiddle.net/3ycrt1qj/

Comment: Ok. But how do i select the class, and where did you find that html? Wasn't there when i searched view-source

Comment: Ok. Got your edit. But how do I select the class? And where even is the class?

Comment: Can i use the ul class like a div class? As in, `.job _listings {background-color: white;}`?

Comment: You can, yes. In your situation, your HTML has a `div` of `.job_listsings` and a `ul` with the same class as a child element.

Comment: my hero dude :-)

Comment: BTW, did you manage to figure out how to display divs in a grid in mobile portrait yet? :-)

Comment: What about if I want to put an inner box shadow for each individual job listing. Tried `.job_listings {background-color: white; box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 18px #888888;} ` but that just puts a shadow for the whole box which jobs are contained within...??

Comment: It's because your outer `div` and `ul` have the class `.job_listings`. You need to add it to the `a` element like: `li.job_listing > a { styles here }`

Comment: Since I don't know what you're actually trying, here's a fiddle with it working: https://jsfiddle.net/drmnoe54/

Comment: One of my main problems now though is creating a grid for ads in mobile portrait....no one seems to be able to answer this one...

Comment: You have four questions open about the same thing. You need to close three of them.

Comment: Haha. I know. Trying to put in a different way to make it clearer and to reach wider audience....

Comment: @Sta I get that, but they will get marked to be closed because of abuse: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled Look under the "Should I flag for moderator attention?" section. Remove three of them and then post the link here to the one you want answered.

Answer (score 1):

There are CSS selector comes in the picture.

you can do that By simply apply css to your element by

```
a[href="https://adsler.co.uk/job/nicos-cleaning-service-london-6-cleaner/"]{
    /*your css properties*/
}
```

Below are some **references** for you

```
    Syntax:  [attribute^=value] 
    Example:  a[href^="https"]  
    Description:  Selects every <a> element whose href 
    attribute value begins with "https"

    Syntax:  [attribute$=value] 
    Example:  a[href$=".pdf"]   
    Description:  Selects every <a> element whose href 
    attribute value ends with ".pdf"

    Syntax:  [attribute*=value] 
    Example:  a[href*="someValue"]  
    Description:  Selects every <a> element whose href 
    attribute value contains the substring "someValue"'
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks. But how do I select the class?